# Excel - Dynamically Accessing External Workbook Information

Tags: excel, path

So i wanted to do this without a Macro if possible.
I wanted to pull in information from an outside spreadsheet, but the path i create consists of multiple cells which populate dynamically (or just by manual input).

I have a spreadsheet with 4 cells.

Cell A1 contains the number `123` in it.

Cell A2 contains =`'H:\\" & A1 & "\Excel\\["& A1 & " - Master Drawing Index (TEST).xlsx]`

Cell A3 contains `Summary Report'!$B$3`

Cell B1 contains `='H:\123\Excel\\[123 - Master Drawing Index (TEST).xlsx]Summary Report'!$B$3`

Cell B1 successfully brings in the value "99" from the referenced spreadsheet

Cell A3 only prints out the path

What am i missing to be able to reference the path correctly and pull the value in Cell A3?

Comment: You will need to use INDIRECT, but since it is volatile it will require the referenced workbook to be open

Comment: INDIRECT does work, but i need to use this on both open and closed workbooks. Is there an excel solution for either case?

Comment: Then you will want vba in a worksheet change event that will change the text into an actual formula.